# Define the selected option in a select after loading

Tags: angular

I have the following scenario:

**variable timezones**

```
["Africa/Abidjan", "Africa/Accra", "Africa/Algiers", "Africa/Bissau", "Africa/Cairo", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Ceuta", "Africa/El_Aaiun", "Africa/Johannesburg", "Africa/Juba", "Africa/Khartoum", "Africa/Lagos", "Africa/Maputo", "Africa/Monrovia", "Africa/Nairobi", "Africa/Ndjamena", "Africa/Sao_Tome", "Africa/Tripoli", "Africa/Tunis", "Africa/Windhoek", "America/Adak", "America/Anchorage", "America/Araguaina", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires", ....... ]
```

(shortened version)

**component.html**

```
<select>
    <option value="0">GMT/UTC</option>
    <option *ngFor="let tz of timezones" [value]="tz">{{tz}}</option>
</select>
```

**compontent.ts**

```
const tzid = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```

In my case, `tzid` is `Europe/Berlin`. How can I define this value as my selected option?

Comment: Do you use template driven forms (`ngModel`) or reactive forms (`FormControl`) ?

Comment: template driven forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using template driven forms, the first step is to define a variable to hold the value in `ts` file, for example, `selectedTimezone` and initialize it to the correct value :

```
selectedTimezone = 'Africa/Tripoli';
```

Then, in the template, use `[(ngModel)]` on the `<select>` tag :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTimezone">
  <option *ngFor="let tz of timezones" [value]="tz">{{tz}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppdavn) showing how it works with both template driven forms and reactive forms.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. This is really easy. I saw so many complicated tutorials and none worked. Thanks a lot!